# Issue with image load stores and compute shaders

Tags: opengl, compute-shader, image-load-store

I am trying to read an input texture, modify it and then write to an output texture from a very simple compute shader.

For some reason I am not able to write to the output image from the compute shader.

The screen is black (even though I have a red clear color).

Here is my application code:

```
    // Compute shader
    (...Code to setup images)
    glTextureStorage2D(m_color_texture, 1, GL_RGB32F, m_src_fbo_size, m_src_fbo_size); // <- Yikes, wrong format!
    glTextureStorage2D(m_temp_texture, 1, GL_RGB32F, m_src_fbo_size, m_src_fbo_size); // <- Yikes, wrong format!
    m_compute_shader.use();
    glBindImageTexture(0, m_color_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glBindImageTexture(1, m_temp_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

    glDispatchCompute(m_info.window_width / 32, m_info.window_height / 32, 1);

    // Full screen quad
    glBindImageTexture(0, m_temp_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    m_full_screen_quad_shader.use();
    glViewport(0, 0, m_info.window_width, m_info.window_height);
    glBindVertexArray(m_full_screen_quad_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

And here is the compute shader:

```
#version 440 core

layout (local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32) in;

layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) readonly uniform image2D input_image;
layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D output_image;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel;
    ivec2 p = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

    texel = imageLoad(input_image, p);
    texel = vec4(1.0) - texel;
    imageStore(output_image, p, texel);
}
```

If I just swap `m_temp_texture` with `m_color_texture` (which is the *input* image )    in the call to `glBindImageTexture(0, m_temp_texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);` then I see the image, so I know it is not a problem with the frag shader. (Here is is though anyway):

```
#version 440 core

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D input_image;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;

//uniform float focal_distance = 50.0;
//uniform float focal_depth = 30.0;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texelFetch(input_image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0).rgba;
    fragColor = color;
}
```

Is there some reason why my compute shader is not being called? Even if I just write `imageStore(output_image, p, vec4(1.0));` in the compute shader, the screen is all black.  I do not know what I am missing.

`glGetError` does not return anything.

**EDIT:**

I originally failed to include the code for the texture creation (the first two lines).  This affects the qustion. Please see the answer below.

Comment: I'm not seeing the part where you use a member barrier to ensure visibility.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - Do we still need to use a memory barrier when 
1) - We aren't reading/writing from/to a same image.
2) - We aren't overwriting any pixel of a image by subsequent `ImageStore`

So there wouldn't be any need for that since every invocation is writing to a separate pixel?

Comment: I think you only need the barrier on the C/C++ side, after the compute shader has run but before passing the texture to the rendering command. Something like glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);

Comment: If you found a solution, post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally mistmatching image formats (`GL_RGB32F` instead of `GL_RGBA32F`) were used in the creation of textures and the call to `glBindImageTexture`.

This error was hard to track down because the format (without alpha) only mattered (in this case) in the compute shader.

Using `GL_RGBA32F`everywhere fixed the issue.